# "Error: Invalid Credentials String When Pushing to GitLab from Another Branch"

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci

This yml file is for GCP-Terraform project.
After pushing to GitLab from another branch, I'm encountering this error: 'Error: The provided credentials string is neither valid JSON nor a valid file path.' Normally, I don't get any errors when pushing from the main code. All credentials are working fine when I push the code from main branch.

I'm attempting to achieve the following: I would like to push from another branch, create a merge request, and once it's approved, have it merged into the main branch. I've looked the branch and merge settings on GitLab; however, I have been unable to find a solution.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```html
image:
   name: hashicorp/terraform:light
   entrypoint:
     - '/usr/bin/env'
     - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

before_script:
     -  rm -rf .terraform
     -  terraform --version
     -  mkdir -p ./creds
     -  echo $SERVICEACCOUNT | base64 -d > ./creds/serviceaamccount.json
     -  export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="./creds/serviceaccount.json"
     -  terraform init

stages:
      - validate
      - plan
      - apply
      - destroy_plan
      - destroy
  
validate:
   stage: validate
   script:
     - terraform validate

plan:
   stage: plan
   script:
     - terraform plan -out "planfile"
   dependencies:
     - validate
   artifacts:
     paths:
       - planfile

apply:
   stage: apply
   script:
     - terraform apply -input=false "planfile"
   dependencies:
     - plan

destroy_plan:
   stage: destroy_plan
   script:
     - terraform plan -destroy -out "destroy_planfile"
   dependencies:
     - validate
   artifacts:
     paths:
       - destroy_planfile
   when: manual

destroy:
   stage: destroy
   script:
     - terraform apply -input=false "destroy_planfile"
   dependencies:
     - destroy_plan
   when: manual
```

Answer (score 0):

`SERVICEACCOUNT` seems to be an environmental variable. Environmental variables can be set as `protected`, which means they will only be available on protected branches.

Your own branch is probably not protected, while `main` usually is. This would explain why it does not work on your branch. In this case `SERVICEACCOUNT` will just contain an empty string.

You can check GitLab environmental variables in the section `settings` -> `CI/CD`, if you have at least maintainer permissions for the project.